# Language dependent custom command

Tags: babel

I would like to define a command that slightly differs depending on the currently selected language in my document. My code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english,french,german]{babel}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[4]{%
    \newcommand{#1}{%
        \iflanguage{english}{#2}{%
        \iflanguage{french}{#3}{%
        \iflanguage{german}{#4}{}%
        }}%
    }%
}
 
\mynewcommand{\uno}{one}{une}{eins}
\newcommand{\whatever}{whatever} % if this is commented out the code works as desired

\begin{document} 

\selectlanguage{english}
\uno
\selectlanguage{french}
\uno

\end{document}
```

Why do I get an error thrown at `\newcommand{\whatever}{whatever}` and how do I avoid that?

### Note:

> In an earlier version I oversimplified my MWE using only two languages, in that case no error is thrown

Comment: Which error? I have no problems.

Comment: I get an error saying `Error: Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: Is that your first error. Please provide also the File List produced in the log-File by `\listfiles`.

Comment: No, you don't; but you surely get lots of spurious spaces.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in the modified example. That's why I proposed a different approach: counting braces is difficult.

Comment: It would be better to change the question, as the cause of the error has been found. "How can I more easily define a command that has this behavior?", for example.

Comment: I agree that this is a bit unfortunate now. I don't see how I could edit the question without you needing to edit your answer though...

Comment: However, a follow up on this question arose: Is it possible to also have starred versions? For example have  `\selectlanguage{english}\uno*` print ONE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The definition seems to be "almost" correct, in that it gives almost the expected result, apart from spurious spaces:

```
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[3]{%
    \newcommand{#1}{%
        \iflanguage{english}{#2}{%
        \iflanguage{french}{#3}{}
        }%
    }%
}
```

However this is error prone if one wanted to augment the supported languages; with `xparse` it's easier:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{m m m}
  {
   \cs_new:Npn #1
     {
      \str_case:onF { \languagename }
        {
         {english}{#2}
         {french}{#3}
        }
        {``No~def~of~\texttt{\token_to_str:N #1}~for~\languagename''}
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If other languages were desired it would be sufficient to add an argument to `\mynewcommand` and the suitable line along the same scheme.

An alternative way might be to define different commands:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newlanguagecommand}[1]{%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifundefined{\string#1\languagename}
      {``No def of \texttt{\string#1} for \languagename''}
      {\@nameuse{\string#1\languagename}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\addtolanguagecommand}[3]{%
  \@namedef{\string#1#2}{#3}}
\makeatother
\newlanguagecommand{\uno}
\addtolanguagecommand{\uno}{english}{one}
\addtolanguagecommand{\uno}{french}{une}
```

Unknown languages will result in "No def of `\command` for *language*"

With `\newlanguagecommand{\uno}` one defines the command so that its expansion is `\\uno<languagename>`; for example, when the language is French, writing `\uno` will use `\\unofrench` which is defined by `\addtolanguagecommand{\uno}{french}{une}` to expand to "une".

This should give no problems also in moving arguments as long as the replacement text doesn't contain fragile commands (text is OK).

---

A revamped `expl3` implementation. The translations are stored in a property list and used according to the current language.

The defined command can receive an optional argument, which should be a valid language name, to force using the corresponding translation independent of the current language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlanguagecommand}{mm}
 {% #1 = command to define
  % #2 = key-value list
  \prop_new:c { \__roepo_nlc_strip:N #1 }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { \__roepo_nlc_strip:N #1 } { #2 }
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o}
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { ##1 }
     {
      \roepo_nlc:NV #1 \languagename
     }
     {
      \roepo_nlc:Nn #1 { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \roepo_nlc:Nn
 {
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { \__roepo_nlc_strip:N #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \prop_item:cn { \__roepo_nlc_strip:N #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    UNSET~TRANSLATION
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \roepo_nlc:Nn { NV }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__roepo_nlc_strip:N { g_roepo_nlc_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _prop }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlanguagecommand{\uno}{
  english=one,
  ngerman=eins,
  french=un
}
\newlanguagecommand{\duck}{
  english=duck,
  ngerman=Ente,
}

\begin{document}

English: \uno{} and \duck{} (\duck[ngerman])

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

Deutsch: \uno{} und \duck{} (\duck[english])

\selectlanguage{french}

Français: \uno{} et \duck{} (\duck[english])

\end{document}
```

[image]