# How to perform macro expansion in an pgfkey

Tags: expansion, pgfkeys

I'm trying to extend the example for multilanguage support shown in here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42791/7561

### The current solution

As it is right now, one needs to define the macro using

```
 \newlangcommand{\uno}
```

and then declare de different outputs one language at a time, like

```
\addtolangcommand{\uno}{english}{one}
\addtolangcommand{\uno}{french}{une}
```

### The expected behavior

However, I want to use that in a single call. For example

\newmlcommand[english=one, french=une]{\uno}

That should declare the `\uno` macro, and then make the `\addtolangcommand` once per pair of language string in the optional argument.

### The problem

I defined that macro as

```
\newcommand{\newmlcommand}[2][]{%
  \newlangcommand#2%
  \pgfkeys{/mlcommands, command=#2, #1}%
}
```

and thought that I will use `pgfkeys` to handle the languages. The idea was to do it with:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /mlcommands/.is family, /mlcommands,
  command/.get=\langcmd,
  .unknown/.code = {%    
    \addtolangcommand{\langcmd}{\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}
  }%
}
```

That is for every pair of `language=string` I will execute the `\addtolangcommand` and assign them to the `\langcmd` temporal macro that holds the original macro passed to `\newmlcommand`.

However, I'm can't get the delay expansion of the macros right. My idea is to execute

```
\addtolangcommand{\langcmd}{language}{string}
```

that was passed using the key pair `language=string`. To achieve that, the `\addlangcommand` should be on hold, and expand both `\langcmd` into the original macro definition and `\pgfkeyscurrentname` into the language string before executing the `\addtolangcommand`. Note that the `\langcmd` is set as parameter using the key pair `command=\macro` that is set in the options in `\newmlcommand`.

However I can't get it right.

### Full code

Here are my attempts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french, english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42791/7561
\newcommand{\newlangcommand}[1]{%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifundefined{\string#1\languagename}
    {``No def of \texttt{\string#1} for \languagename''}
    {\@nameuse{\string#1\languagename}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\addtolangcommand}[3]{%  
  \@namedef{\string#1#2}{#3}}    

\def\langcmd{}
\pgfkeys{
  /mlcommands/.is family, /mlcommands,
  command/.get=\langcmd,
  .unknown/.code = {%    
    % tried this idea: save it in a macro and execute it later
    % but, the expansion is still a problem
    % \def\tmp{\noexpand\addtolangcommand{\langcmd}{\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}}%
    % \tmp%
    % and this idea: try to delay the expansion of addtolangcommand
    % \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addtolangcommand\expandafter\expandafter{\langcmd}\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}%
    % and the naive aplication doesn't work either
    \addtolangcommand{\langcmd}{\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}
  }%
}

\newcommand{\newmlcommand}[2][]{%
  \newlangcommand#2%
  \pgfkeys{/mlcommands, command=#2, #1}%
}
\makeatother

% How to use (original)
%\newlangcommand{\uno}
%\addtolangcommand{\uno}{english}{one}
%\addtolangcommand{\uno}{french}{une}

% or the new (non working way)
\newmlcommand[english=one, french=une]{\uno}


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\uno  

\selectlanguage{french}
\uno  

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\uno  

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a bit confusing. Which one should be expanded ? That looks like a TeX problem independent from pgfkeys

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do the expansion, in such a way that everytime each pair `english=string` executes `\addtolangcommand{\cmd}{english}{string}` where `\cmd` is the macro passed as parameter in `command=\macro` in the definition of the `\newmlcommand`.

Comment: I don't know what it should do but the annoying part can be used as `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addtolangcommand\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\langcmd\expandafter}\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}`

Comment: That compiles, but does not achieve what I'm trying to do. I added more details to see if that clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

There were two things:

- The macro expansion needed the [`2n-1` rule for the `\expandafter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104508/7561), and protect all the brackets before the parameters.
- The macro inside the `pgfkeys` didn't work with the `.get` key, so I did a manual `\def`.

After that the macro `\addtolangcommand` will be expanded after the parameters.

### Solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42791/7561
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newlcommand}[1]{%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifundefined{\string#1\languagename}
    {``No def of \texttt{\string#1} for \languagename''}
    {\@nameuse{\string#1\languagename}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\addtolangcommand}[3]{%
  \@namedef{\string#1#2}{#3}}

%\def\langcmd{}
\pgfkeys{
  /mlcommands/.is family, /mlcommands,
  command/.code={\def\langcmd{#1}},
  .unknown/.code = {%    
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addtolangcommand\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\langcmd\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfkeyscurrentname\expandafter}\expandafter
    {#1}
  }%
}

\newcommand{\newmlcommand}[2][]{%
  \newlcommand#2%
  \pgfkeys{/mlcommands, command=#2, #1}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newmlcommand[english=ONE, spanish=UNO]{\uno}
\selectlanguage{english}
\uno

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\uno

\end{document}
```