# Change the text depending on the language

Tags: babel

This is probably a rather simple question, but I couldn't find it answered:
When I write e.g.

```
\pageref{Example}
```

the output is `on page 12` for babel language English, but `auf Seite 12` for babel language German.

I want to create custom language sets like this:

```
\createTranslation{insertTableTitle}
{english=Something, german=Etwas, italiano=Alcuno, default=Something}
```

When I call `\insertTableTitle` it expands to different strings, depending on the language. This example is pseudocode of course, but I'm pretty sure, there is some built-in command in babel that does the job.

What is the default way to do this or how is it handled at e.g. the title of the table of content?

Comment: The bog-standard builtin `\pageref` only prints the page number, not `on page 12`. You are loading some package with smart referencing; which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you write a conditional :-)
How you implement the conditional there are options.

For example, the `varioref` package uses package options (avoiding `babel` altogether). Behold (copied from `varioref.sty`):

```
\DeclareOption{american}
  {\vref@addto\extrasamerican{%
    \def\reftextfaceafter {on the \reftextvario{facing}{next} page}%
    \def\reftextfacebefore{on the \reftextvario{facing}{preceding}
                           page}%
    \def\reftextafter     {on the \reftextvario{following}{next} page}%
    \def\reftextbefore    {on the \reftextvario{preceding}{previous} page}%
    \def\reftextcurrent   {on \reftextvario{this}{the current} page}%
    \def\reftextfaraway#1{on page~\pageref{#1}}%
    \def\reftextpagerange#1#2{on pages~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
    \def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} to~\ref{#2}}%
    \let\vrefformat\vrefdefaultformat
    \let\Vrefformat\Vrefdefaultformat
    \let\fullrefformat\fullrefdefaultformat
    \let\vrefrangeformat\vrefrangedefaultformat
  }}
\DeclareOption{arabic}
  {\vref@addto\extrasarabic{%
    \def\reftextfaceafter {بالصفحة \reftextvario{المقابلة}{اللاحقة}}%
    \def\reftextfacebefore{بالصفحة \reftextvario{المقابلة}{المُنْصَرِمَةٌ}}%
    \def\reftextafter     {بالصفحة \reftextvario{اللاحقة}{التالية}}%
    \def\reftextbefore    {بالصفحة \reftextvario{السابقة}{المُنْصَرِمَةٌ}}%
    \def\reftextcurrent   {ب\reftextvario{الصفحة الحالية}{هذه الصفحة}}%
    \def\reftextfaraway#1{بالصفحة رقم~\pageref{#1}}%
    \def\reftextpagerange#1#2{بالصفحات~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
    \def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} حتى~\ref{#2}}%
    \let\vrefformat\vrefdefaultformat
    \let\Vrefformat\Vrefdefaultformat
    \let\fullrefformat\fullrefdefaultformat
    \let\vrefrangeformat\vrefrangedefaultformat
  }}
\DeclareOption{austrian}
  {\vref@addto\extrasaustrian{%
    \def\reftextfaceafter {auf der n\"achsten Seite}%
    \def\reftextfacebefore{auf der vorherigen Seite}%
    \let\reftextafter     \reftextfaceafter
    \let\reftextbefore    \reftextfacebefore
    \def\reftextcurrent   {auf dieser Seite}%
    \def\reftextfaraway#1{auf Seite~\pageref{#1}}%
    \def\reftextpagerange#1#2{auf Seiten~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
    \def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} bis~\ref{#2}}%
    \let\vrefrangeformat\vrefrangedefaultformat
  }}
```

If you want a `babel`-based solution, you can use the conditional

```
\iflanguage{<language>}{<true action>}{<false action>}
```

So something like

```
\newcommand\mytabletitle{%
   \iflanguage{english}{Something}{%
   \iflanguage{german}{Etwas}{%
   \iflanguage{italiano}{Alcuno}{%
      Something %default
   }}}}
```

and make your command print `\mytabletitle` instead of any hard-coded string of letters.

[The answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42784/language-dependent-custom-command) gives some other ways of using babel-based conditionals. Specifically, egreg provides a revamped version that uses a key-value syntax as you asked for in your original question. Rather than stealing his answer I'll just point you to it.

Comment: iflanguage was the thing I was looking for. Is there any reason, why I should avoid babel? Or is it safe and conflict free?

Comment: Not that I know of (any reason to avoid babel).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `translator` package. That's what e.g. Beamer uses to translate strings like "Figure".

You'll find that it already comes with translations for many commonly used terms in its dictionaries, but you can also add new ones:

```
\documentclass[
ngerman
%english
]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-basic-dictionary}

\newtranslation[to = German]{Something}{Etwas}
\newtranslation[to = Italian]{Something}{Alcuno}


\begin{document}

\translate{table}

\translate{Something}

\end{document}
```